# Equivalent of fragment in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

How will achieve the above with a bottom static menu and replaceable uiviewcontrollers like fragments in android in the middle part?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use view controller container:

> View controller containers are objects whose responsibility is to manage some set of view controllers, displaying or hiding them as required.

Take a look at these links :

[Writing high-quality view controller containers](http://subjective-objective-c.blogspot.de/2011/08/writing-high-quality-view-controller.html)

[WWDC Session 102 - Implementing UIViewController Containment.](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102)

Answer (score 2):

**Container views** is the way to go 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Recently, I also had the same requirement, want something like fragments in android ,and easily fulfilled by the use Container views.

*Good tutorial with demo project:* 
http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers